# python pandas - get a min function from a given row to the end of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe such as the following

```
                         low   MFE_pr              MFE_ts  MAE_pr
exit_time                                                        
2000-02-01 01:00:00  1400.25  1400.25 2000-02-01 01:00:00     NaN
2000-02-01 01:30:00  1399.50  1399.50 2000-02-01 01:30:00     NaN
2000-02-01 02:00:00  1399.75  1399.50 2000-02-01 01:30:00     NaN
2000-02-01 02:30:00  1399.25  1399.25 2000-02-01 02:30:00     NaN
2000-02-01 03:00:00  1399.50  1399.25 2000-02-01 02:30:00     NaN
2000-02-01 03:30:00  1398.25  1398.25 2000-02-01 03:30:00     NaN
2000-02-01 04:00:00  1398.25  1398.25 2000-02-01 03:30:00     NaN
2000-02-01 04:30:00  1399.00  1398.25 2000-02-01 03:30:00     NaN
2000-02-01 05:00:00  1399.25  1398.25 2000-02-01 03:30:00     NaN
2000-02-01 05:30:00  1399.50  1398.25 2000-02-01 03:30:00     NaN
```

I want to populate the MAE_pr column with the min function in a way similar to the following:

```
trade ['MAE_pr'] = trade.low.min()
```

However i dont want the min of each row to be computed on the entire column, but for each row from the low value at the timestamp mentionned at MFE_ts to the end of the table.

How would i go about to select such a subset on which to perform the min?

For instance for the last row min would be computed on the value of the "low" column from timestamp 3:30 to the end of the table

Comment: Do you want to select a specific period of time and then apply `cummin()` to period selected?

Comment: yes, for instance for the last row cummin would be computed on the value of the "low" column from timestamp 3:30 to the end of the table

Comment: cummin returns a vector, yet you have only a scalar cell to fill for each result. So among all the values of the resulting cummin vector starting at 3:30, what is the value you select to fill in MFE_pr?

Comment: Yes you are right, this should simply be min function not cummin. I will edit the question

Answer (score 1):

The idea with `cummin` is actually a good starting point to get a vectorized algorithm. The thing to figure out is that you are actually searching for a *reverse `cummin`*: from a given point to the end is a cummin if your dataframe in upside down. So let's do it. Sort the dataframe descending and calculate the cummin against the low column:

```
df['rcummin'] = df.sort_index(ascending=False).low.cummin()
```

`rcummin` now contains the cumulative minimum you were searching for. You have now to fetch the appropriate value to get the corresponding min for each `MFE_ts` datetime. You have already indexed the dataframe with the time series datetimes: doing such a right thing makes it easy:

```
df.MAE_pr = df.loc[df.MFE_ts].rcummin
df.MAE_pr

exit_time
2000-02-01 01:00:00    1398.25
2000-02-01 01:30:00    1398.25
2000-02-01 01:30:00    1398.25
2000-02-01 02:30:00    1398.25
2000-02-01 02:30:00    1398.25
2000-02-01 03:30:00    1398.25
2000-02-01 03:30:00    1398.25
2000-02-01 03:30:00    1398.25
2000-02-01 03:30:00    1398.25
2000-02-01 03:30:00    1398.25
Name: rcummin, dtype: float64
```

Your data example is not cool to visualize the result but say you have one datetime at 4:30 and you'll get 1399.00 as a result for that row.